# Как работает функция click в jquery?

Tags: jquery

Вот например, что делает вот эта?

```
$button.click(getImages.bind(null, $images, $query));
```

Насколько мне удалось убедиться, так после загрузки страницы "кнопка $button нажимается сама", проверяю так:

```
$button.click(getImages.bind(null, $images, $query),alert('Ку ку'));
```

Сразу окошко вылетает.
А вот еще один прикол, перед этой строчкой объявляются переменные, такого формата:

```
$query = $('#squery').val();
$button = $('#search');
$getstr = $('.ctrl-middl');
```

Честно говоря, чего они такого формата ($ в начале, читал, что вроде как кешированные). Так вот $query это у меня поле, а $button это кнопка, по ее нажатию должно брать из поля vaue и записывать в $query, вот так:

```
$button.click($query = $('#squery').val(), getImages.bind(null, $images, $query));
```

Вместо этого, оно использует, только то значение которое записано в самом value поля. Причем если менять значение и жать кнопку, все равно остается старое.
Извиняюсь, я просто не очень в js, поэтому это может быть вообще банальщина

---

Так у меня тут вообще "койдодыр":

```js
$query = $('#squery').val();
$button = $('#search');
$getstr = $('.ctrl-middl');

$images = $('#image');
$videos = $('#video');
$descr = $('#descr');
$genre = $('#genre');

$button.click(getImages.bind(null, $images, $query));

function showImageSearchResult(result) {
  for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    $images.append(createThumbnail(result.items[i].snippet, result.items[i].link));
  }
}

function createThumbnail(snippet, link) {
  $images.css('background-image', 'url(' + link + ')');
  return $images;
}

function getImages(imageContainer, query) {
  imageContainer.empty();
  $.get(
      "https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?", {
        "q": query + " wallpaper",
        "searchType": "image",
        "imageSize": "large",
        "key": "AIzaSyDQ7ablMI0Ee4kwu8h6IsYh82TuinT8Fy8",
        "cx": "013005726503347959821:ejgclbwxiii"
      })
    .done(showImageSearchResult)
    .fail(function() {
      imageContainer.html('<p class="err">Не удалось вывести изображения, попробуйте позже.</p>');
    });
}
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Play');
* {
  font-family: 'Play', sans-serif;
  box-sizing: border-box
}

:root {
  --color-1: #888;
  --color-2: #aaa;
  --color-3: #ddd;
  --color-4: #eee;
  --color-5: #ffaa2f;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0
}


/*-----------------------*/

main {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: var(--color-4);
}

header {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 10%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid var(--color-1);
  z-index: 2;
}

input {
  padding: 0 2vh
}

input:hover {
  background: var(--color-3)
}

textarea {
  resize: none;
  padding: 2vh
}

textarea,
input {
  position: absolute;
  color: var(--color-1);
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
  font-size: 3vw;
  transition: .5s;
}

input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: var(--color-1);
  transition: .5s
}

input::-moz-placeholder {
  color: var(--color-1);
  transition: .5s
}

input:hover::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: var(--color-2)
}

input:hover::-moz-placeholder {
  color: var(--color-2)
}

#squery {
  height: 100%;
  width: 70%;
  left: 0;
  background: var(--color-3);
  border-right: 1px solid var(--color-1);
}

#search {
  height: 100%;
  width: 30%;
  right: 0;
  background: var(--color-2);
  color: var(--color-4);
  border-left: 1px solid var(--color-1);
  text-transform: uppercase;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-size: 50% 50%;
  background-position: right;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#search:hover {
  background: var(--color-5);
  color: var(--color-1)
}


/*-----------------------*/

section {
  width: 100%;
  height: 30%;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}

section div {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border-top: 1px solid var(--color-1);
  border-bottom: 1px solid var(--color-1);
  background: var(--color-4);
}

section div input {
  width: 100%;
  height: 20%;
  top: 0;
  font-size: 2vw;
  border-bottom: 1px solid var(--color-1);
  background-size: 50% 50%;
  background-position: right;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

section div textarea {
  width: 100%;
  height: 80%;
  bottom: 0;
  font-size: 1vw;
  border-top: 1px solid var(--color-1);
  background-size: 50% 50%;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#image {
  width: 30%;
  left: 0;
  border-right: 1px solid var(--color-1);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#video {
  width: 40%;
  left: 30%;
  right: 30%;
  border-left: 1px solid var(--color-1);
  border-right: 1px solid var(--color-1);
  background-size: 50% 50%;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#artcl {
  width: 30%;
  right: 0;
  border-left: 1px solid var(--color-1);
}


/*-----------------------*/

#result {
  width: 90%;
  height: 50%;
  right: 0;
  font-size: 1vw;
  border-top: 1px solid var(--color-1);
  background-size: 50% 50%;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  z-index: 0;
}


/*-----------------------*/

#control {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  transition: .5s;
  pointer-events: none;
  z-index: 1;
}

#control div {
  position: absolute;
  background: var(--color-3);
  pointer-events: auto;
  transition: .5s;
}

#control .ctrl-left {
  width: 10%;
  height: 60%;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  border-right: 2px solid var(--color-1);
  border-top: 1px solid var(--color-1);
}

#control .ctrl-bott {
  width: 100%;
  height: 10%;
  bottom: 0;
  border-top: 2px solid var(--color-1);
}

#control .ctrl-middl {
  width: 10%;
  height: 10%;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: var(--color-5);
  cursor: pointer;
  border-right: 2px solid var(--color-1);
  border-top: 2px solid var(--color-1);
  z-index: 2;
  background-size: 50% 50%;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#control .ctrl-middl:hover {
  background: var(--color-2);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>SimpleGrabber</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.min.css">
  <script src="js/prefixfree.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <main>
    <header>
      <input id="squery" type="text" value="cat" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Введите запрос...">
      <input id="search" type="button" value="Найти">
    </header>
    <section>
      <div id="image"></div>
      <div id="video"></div>
      <div id="artcl">
        <input id="genre" type="text" valu="" placeholder="Жанры">
        <textarea id="descr"></textarea>
      </div>
    </section>
    <textarea id="result"></textarea>
    <div id="control">
      <div class="ctrl-left"></div>
      <div class="ctrl-middl"></div>
      <div class="ctrl-bott"></div>
    </div>
  </main>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Плюс еще и мои правки.

---

На самом деле, мне просто нужен скрипт, что бы по запросу в поле, выдавал:

1. Случайную картинку из Googl'a
2. Случайный ролик с YouTub'a
3. И краткое описание, спарсенное со стороннего сайта

Пока, только картинку загружает нормально, а парсер выдает весь код указанной страницы, и чего-то не могу достучаться до парсенных элементов.

```
var parse;

$.ajaxPrefilter( function (options) {
  if (options.crossDomain && jQuery.support.cors) {
    var http = (window.location.protocol === 'http:' ? 'http:' : 'https:');
    options.url = http + '//cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/' + options.url;
    //options.url = "http://cors.corsproxy.io/url=" + options.url;
  }
});

$.get(
    'https://game-shop.com.ua/category/igryi-dlya-playstation-4',
    function(response) {
      parse = response;
      return parse;
    });

$('.ctrl-middl').on('click', function() {
    $('#result').html(parse);
    alert('parsed ok!');
});
```

Comment: `$button.disappear;alert('Ку ку')` - А вот так кнопка исчезает по загрузке страницы. Сразу окошко вылетает.

Comment: В чём конкретно ваш вопрос?

Comment: Если кратко: вы поняли неправильно вообще всё и код написали неправильный

Comment: Вы может помочь исправить, данный код?
Выбрать правильный метод?

Answer (score 0):

[`.сlick()`](https://api.jquery.com/click/) работает в 3 вариантах:

```
.click( handler ) // вешается обработчик события
.click( eventData , handler ) // вешается обработчик события, и в него передаются данные
.click() // эмулируется нажатие
```

`handler` - это обработчик события. Теперь поставьте себя на место JS.

Он знает, что в `click` может быть передано 0, 1 или 2 аргумента. Если как в первом случае передается один, значит, там должен быть `handler` - обработчик события, те ссылка на функцию. А там функция. JS выполняет эту функцию, ожидая, что результатом выполнения функции будет ссылка на функцию. Т.е `getImages.bind` возвращает обработчик события.

Теперь второй пример, вы добавили алерт. Это значит, что вместо  `.click( handler )`, будет такой вариант функции: `.click( eventData , handler )`. И JS теперь слепо выполняет `alert` пытаясь получить от него обработчик события, которого уже нет

Что касаемо `$` в начале переменной - это бред. От названия переменных ничего не зависит. Но многие любят ставить  `$`, чтобы обозначить, что переменная содержит jQuery-объект

Comment: _Я не знаю что возвращает getImages.bind, но не думаю, что функцию._ - можно считать, что функцию

Comment: bind не выполняет функцию, поэтому строка `$button.click(getImages.bind(null, $images, $query))` вполне корректна. В данном случае просто устанавливаются значения параметров. То есть при срабатывании обработчика `function getImages(imageContainer, query) {` параметры будут заполнены соответственно _$images_ и _$query_. Так как _bind не выполняет функцию_ твои варианты при сломают ожидаемое поведение, так как функция _getImages_ не будет выполнена

Comment: @Grundy подстава, не знал. Поменял ответ

Comment: Как же мне сделать, что бы $query менялся в getImages.bind ?
unbind делать? как?

Comment: @KRIVA, зачем ты вообще `bind` делаешь? и что значит _менялся_?